# Data tranfromation with if then else

Tags: if-statement, sas

I have a table as below:

```
  id   term   subj   degree
  18    2007   ww     Yes
  32    2015   AA     Yes
  32    2016   AA     No
  25    2011   NM     No
  25    2001   ts     No

  18    2009   ww     Yes
  18    2010   ww     No
```

I need another variable term2 if the degree is Yes, and I will write to term2 whatever same id and subj's term. So means:

```
  id    term   subj   degree   term2
  18    2007   ww     Yes       2009
  32    2015   AA     Yes       2016
  32    2016   AA     No         0
  25    2011   NM     No         0
  25    2001   ts     No         0

  18    2009   ww     Yes       2010  
  18    2010   ww     No         0
```

What I did with if then else doesn't work. Any idea? Thank you

this is the one I used

```
  data have;
    merge aa aa (rename=(id=id1 subj=subj1     
        term=term1);
    term2=0;
    if id=id1 and subj=subj1 and degree="Yes" then
     term2=term1

   run;
```

Comment: What did you do with if then else?  In what way did it not work?

Comment: Please show your code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is missing some important information, like, when an id has an degree = yes value, is there always a degree = no row with the same id?
What should be done if there are more then one degree=no rows with different terms for an id if it also has an degree=yes value? Why do you want to solve this with an if-else Statement? 
Assuming you have always exactly one id-matching degree=no row for a row with degree = yes you can use this:

```
Proc sql;
 Select a.*, case when a.degree = "Yes" then b.term else 0 end from table as a
 left outer join table as b on a.id = b.id and b.degree = "No" and a.degree="Yes";
quit;
```

This is without if-statement and no datastep, but you must provide more information if you want a more specific solution.

Comment: ERROR: Result of WHEN clause 2 is not the same data type as the preceding results.

Comment: I changed the table based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input id   term   subj $  degree $;
cards;
  32    2015   AA     Yes
  32    2016   AA     No
  25    2011   NM     No
  25    2001   ts     No
  18    2007   ww     Yes
  18    2010   ww     No
;

data want;
   merge have have(firstobs=2 keep=id term rename=(id=_id term=_term));
   term2=0;
   if id=_id and degree='Yes' then term2=_term;
   drop _:;
run;
```

Comment: It works but for a reason not all of them. Many Yes values have '0' term2. Some of them right

Comment: I updated question based on why doesn't work. It works only if the same value right after other value. Otherwise doesn't work.

Comment: So you have to sort your data by id first.